# Detect if MTD partition is UBI formatted

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, flash-memory, ubifs

Is there a reliable way to know if an MTD partition (e.g. /dev/mtd0) has already been UBI formatted? I intend to have such a test in a startup script (bash) which calls ubiattach only on MTD partitions which are UBI formatted. For me "blkid" does not seem to give any information about mtd partitions. Neither could I find a relevant entry for that in "/sys/class/mtd/".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mtdinfo to check the MTD type:

```
# mtdinfo /dev/mtd0
mtd0
Name:                           40000000.flash
Type:                           nor
Eraseblock size:                262144 bytes, 256.0 KiB
Amount of eraseblocks:          512 (134217728 bytes, 128.0 MiB)
Minimum input/output unit size: 1 byte
Sub-page size:                  1 byte
Character device major/minor:   90:0
Bad blocks are allowed:         false
Device is writable:             true

# mtdinfo /dev/mtd2
mtd2
Name:                           rootfs
Type:                           ubi
Eraseblock size:                262016 bytes, 255.9 KiB
Amount of eraseblocks:          257 (67338112 bytes, 64.2 MiB)
Minimum input/output unit size: 1 byte
Sub-page size:                  1 byte
Character device major/minor:   90:4
Bad blocks are allowed:         false
Device is writable:             true
```

As the example shows, the `/dev/mtd2` is ubi!

And you can download the mtd-utils form http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/

mtdinfo is in the package and you need build it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually did try mtdinfo, but in my case the "Type" is always "nand" or "nor". It does not say "ubi" even when I format it as ubi using ubiformat.

Comment: @Rogue Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @cosimo193 Nopes. I had to use a very ugly workaround: I had another persistent memory in my system: an eeprom. I used a bit in the eeprom to mark if the nand/nor has been formatted.

Comment: `mtdinfo` only returns type `ubi` for _emulated MTD devices_ (kernel option MTD_UBI_GLUEBI=y).  It does not tell you if a NOR flash partition contains a UBI volume.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `file` command available then you can tell it to ignore that the `/dev/mtdX` is a special device (`-s` flag) and look at the contents.  For example, a u-boot bootloader or a kernel (FIT image)<sup>*</sup>:

```
$ file -s /dev/mtd0
/dev/mtd0: data
$ file -s /dev/mtd1
/dev/mtd1: data
```

a u-boot bootscript:

```
$ file -s /dev/mtd2
/dev/mtd2: u-boot legacy uImage, Boot Script, Linux/ARM, Script File (Not compressed), 2050 bytes, Wed Jun 15 20:58:22 2022, Load Address: 0x00000000, Entry Point: 0x00000000, Header CRC: 0xD0B28CF0, Data CRC: 0x7EBACC8D
```

and a *UBI-formatted MTD partition*:

```
$ file -s /dev/mtd3
/dev/mtd3: UBI image, version 1
```

<sup>*</sup> use `cat ${DEVICE} > /tmp/tmp.img; dumpimage -l /tmp/tmp.img` to examine FIT images